# docopt linker error for example program

Tags: c++, linker-errors, docopt

I am trying to compile the example code from the github page of docopt. I am getting a linker error though:

```
/tmp/test-d3ed6b.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0xf3): undefined reference to `docopt::docopt(std::string const&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&, bool, std::string const&, bool)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x1c8): undefined reference to `docopt::operator<<(std::ostream&, docopt::value const&)'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have a file `test.cpp` and a directory `docopt` with all the docopt files in it.

`test.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "docopt/docopt.h"

static const char USAGE[] =
R"(Naval Fate.

Usage:
naval_fate ship new <name>...
naval_fate ship <name> move <x> <y> [--speed=<kn>]
naval_fate ship shoot <x> <y>
naval_fate mine (set|remove) <x> <y> [--moored | --drifting]
naval_fate (-h | --help)
naval_fate --version

Options:
-h --help     Show this screen.
--version     Show version.
--speed=<kn>  Speed in knots [default: 10].
--moored      Moored (anchored) mine.
--drifting    Drifting mine.
)";

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    std::map<std::string, docopt::value> args
    = docopt::docopt(USAGE,
                     { argv + 1, argv + argc },
                     true,               // show help if requested
                     "Naval Fate 2.0");  // version string

    for(auto const& arg : args) {
        std::cout << arg.first <<  arg.second << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

what is with that error? How can I fix that? I have tried clang-3.5 and g++

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this as well.

I resolved the problem using `cmake` and some specific configuration in my `CMakeLists.txt`. The following configuration worked for me:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5)
project(my_project)
include(ExternalProject)

set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11" )

set(DOCOPT_ROOT ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/external/docopt)
set(DOCOPT_INCLUDE_DIRS ${DOCOPT_ROOT}/include/docopt)
set(DOCOPT_LIBRARIES ${DOCOPT_ROOT}/lib/libdocopt.a)
set(docopt_INSTALL_DIR "${DOCOPT_ROOT}")
set(docopt_CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${docopt_INSTALL_DIR})

ExternalProject_Add(docopt
  PREFIX ${DOCOPT_ROOT}
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/docopt/docopt.cpp.git
  BINARY_DIR ${DOCOPT_ROOT}
  INSTALL_DIR ${DOCOPT_ROOT}
  CMAKE_ARGS ${docopt_CMAKE_ARGS}
  LOG_DOWNLOAD ON
  LOG_CONFIGURE ON
  LOG_BUILD ON
  LOG_INSTALL ON
)
add_library(libdocopt STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libdocopt PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${DOCOPT_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(libdocopt docopt)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
include_directories(${DOCOPT_INCLUDE_DIRS})

file(GLOB projector_src
  "*.h"
  "*.cpp"
  )

add_executable(my_project ${my_project_src})
target_link_libraries(projector libdocopt)
```

Obviously, you don't need to use `cmake`, but instead you'll need to either put the source for `docopt.cpp` in with your own code or else you'll need to tell the linker where to look for it. `cmake` does take care of this for you, but it's one more thing to worry about.

Comment: Is "projector" the name of your project?

Comment: Yes. The project name is 'projector'

Answer (score 0):

Modified Jeremiah Peschka's answer to work out of the box independently of any other sources.

Project structure:

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── build
└── main.cpp
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5)
project(my_project)
include(ExternalProject)

set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11" )

set(DOCOPT_ROOT ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/external/docopt)
set(DOCOPT_INCLUDE_DIRS ${DOCOPT_ROOT}/include/docopt)
set(DOCOPT_LIBRARIES ${DOCOPT_ROOT}/lib/libdocopt.a)
set(docopt_INSTALL_DIR "${DOCOPT_ROOT}")
set(docopt_CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${docopt_INSTALL_DIR})

ExternalProject_Add(docopt
  PREFIX ${DOCOPT_ROOT}
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/docopt/docopt.cpp.git
  BINARY_DIR ${DOCOPT_ROOT}
  INSTALL_DIR ${DOCOPT_ROOT}
  CMAKE_ARGS ${docopt_CMAKE_ARGS}
  LOG_DOWNLOAD ON
  LOG_CONFIGURE ON
  LOG_BUILD ON
  LOG_INSTALL ON
)

add_library(libdocopt STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libdocopt PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${DOCOPT_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(libdocopt docopt)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
include_directories(${DOCOPT_INCLUDE_DIRS})

file(GLOB src
  "*.h"
  "*.cpp"
  )

add_executable(my_project ${src})
target_link_libraries(my_project libdocopt)
```